# Dart:How to convert simple map into list in dart/flutter?

Tags: arrays, list, dictionary, flutter, dart

I want to convert a simple map to into a list currently I am having `{Jack: 23, Adam: 27, Katherin: 25}`
and want to achieve `[{ Jack, 23 }, { Adam, 27 }, { Katherin, 25 }]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find an example, the key -  using `map.entries`

```
class Person {
  final String name;
  final int age;

  Person(this.name, this.age);
}

void test() {
  final map = <String, int>{"Jack": 23, "Adam": 27, "Katherin": 25};

  final list = map.entries.map((entry) => Person(entry.key, entry.value)).toList();
}
```

If you don't want to use Person class, you can use the package with tuple
https://pub.dev/packages/tuple

Comment: But suppose I don't have a model then what to do or person class?

Comment: You can use package which provides tuple functionality or create Person class(for me it's better)
Check updated answer

Comment: Can i add a map into a list one by one? then this will also resolve my issue?

Comment: Sure, you can add to list items where item is map, and will have 
`List<Map<String, int>> list = map.entries.map((entry) => <String, int>{entry.key: entry.value}).toList();`

But I do not recommend this way